# Is there any formula of monadic second-order logic that is only satisfied by an infinite set?

Tags: logic, higher-order-logic

Is there any formula, of monadic second-order logic, that is only satisfied by an infinite set?

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be *no*, given that we cannot express Dedekind-infinite 'property', i.e. that a set is infinite, in monadic logic?

Comment: @prime4567: Can you prove that? All that is obvious is that the usual characterization of Dedekind-infiniteness is not expressible (since it quantifies over functions, not just subsets of the universe).

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: it is indeed not obvious. It does follow from the result of Skolem that I refer to in my answer to the question.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Indeed, I was somewhat too quick there. The identity 'infinite(x) iff Dedekind-infinite(x)' apparently cannot be proven in ZF without the assumption of the axiom of choice.

Comment: @prime4567: That is true, but somewhat irrelevant. I think we can assume the axiom of choice in the universe unless stated otherwise.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila But suppose that the identity 'infinite(x) iff Dedekind-infinite(x)' holds. I know it can't be proven in ZF without AC. But suppose it holds. Denote 'Dedekind-infinite(x)' with D(x). So suppose we find the formula $\varphi(x)$ that satisfies the above criteria of the OP. Then $\varphi(x)$ is true, but $\varphi(x) \rightarrow D(x)$ should also be true, so D(x) should be true, and it would be odd if it were inexpressible.

Comment: @prime4567: I still don't see the point. Using Dedekind-infiniteness to characterize infinite sets is easily doable in a first-order logic that includes a single unary function symbol. So you're trying to say that it doesn't work without the axiom of choice because...? And *again*, unless stated otherwise, it's probably safe to assume the axiom of choice holds.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Let's assume AC, as you suggested. That's not the point. The point is that if 'infinite' were to be equivalent to 'Dedekind-infinite', then $\varphi(x)$ entails D(x), so D(x) should be true, but isn't it a problem that D(x) isn't expressible in MSOL whenever $\varphi(x)$ is, given that D(x) should be true whenever $\varphi(x)$ is?

Comment: @prime4567: Again, being Dedekind-infinite is expressible in first-order logic with a function symbol. You somehow implicitly assume that if something is expressible without choice, then it is provable to be always true without choice as well.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila You're right. The answer to the above problem does boil down to 'infinite(x)' where x is a set being expressible in MSOL, right?

Comment: @prime4567: without AC, Dedekind infinite implies not finite, it is the converse that needs AC. So you don't need to use AC in the metalanguage, to prove the theory of a one-to-one but not onto function only has infinite models. However in MSOL, you can't quantify over functions.

Comment: The answer will likely depend on the signature. The theory of second-order arithmetic is written entirely in monadic second-order logic, and every model is infinite - of course the *language* includes function symbols, but all second-order quantifiers are set quantifiers.  I suspect you are asking about the theory of equality in second-order monadic logic, or something like that. The question should be more precise about the restrictions on the language. Indeed, every first-order axiomatization can be view as if it was in monadic second order logic...

Answer (score 2):

Skolem proved a quantifier elimination result for Peirce's "Calculus of Classes". See this [article in the Stanford Encyclopaedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/algebra-logic-tradition/) for some references. This calculus amounts to the first-order theory over the signature $(\subseteq; \emptyset, -, \cup, \cap)$ of type $(2; 0, 1, 2, 2)$ whose intended interpretation is the set of subsets of some universe with $\subseteq$ being the subset relation,with $\emptyset$ denoting the empty set and with $-$, $\cup$ and $\cap$ denoting complementation, union and intersection.

Skolem's result shows that every sentence is equivalent to a propositional combination of sentences $L_n$ ($n = 1, 2, \ldots)$, where $L_n$ means "the universe has at least $n$ elements". Monadic second order logic can be reduced to the theory of the Calculus of Classes by mapping sets to themselves and by treating elements as singleton sets, noting that singleton sets are the atoms for the subset relation. A satisfiable propositional combination of the sentences $L_n$ is satisfiable in a finite universe, hence a satisfiable sentence of the form $\exists x.\phi$ is satisfiable with a witness for $x$ that is finite.