# "there are infinitely many" with finitely many variables

Tags: logic, model-theory, quantifiers

I vaguely recall reading somewhere that one cannot say "there are infinitely may" using a formula with only finitely many variables.

A bit more precisely, let $\mathcal L$ be the result of extending first-order logic to include disjunctions of length $\kappa$ which do not introduce infinitely many variables into a formula.

Now one way of putting the question is...  Is there an $\mathcal L$-formula $A$ in the one monadic predicate $F$ such that

$\mathcal M\models A$ iff $F^\mathcal M$ is infinite

for all structures $\mathcal M$ for $\mathcal S$?

Seems like there must be a very elementary observation to use here, but I can't quite see it.

Comment: I think this question was asked before in one version or another. Either with one predicate or in monadic second-order logic. I can't remember, and I have to go. But it might be worth looking around. ***EDIT.*** Okay, found it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247425/is-there-any-formula-of-monadic-second-order-logic-that-is-only-satisfied-by-an/

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, at least that settles it.  ...I vaguely recall an observation to the effect of "formulas with at most $n$ variables all have property blah".